# unable to properly use the resqult of an sql query in php

Tags: php, sql

What I'm trying to do is take the number of rows that meet a certain requirement, and depending on the number that do, the script will do different things.

my code:

```
        $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(email)FROM subscribers WHERE id= ?";
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->bind_param("s", $id);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $callbacks = $stmt2->get_result();
        while($rows = $callbacks->fetch_assoc()){
            $results = $rows;
        }
        $stmt2->close();

        if ($results <2001){
            $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
        }else{
            $email_err = "This user has reached the limmit to what their plan can allow .";
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm unsure of how to actually use the number of rows.

In this configuration, it doesn't care what the number of results is, it just posts them anyways.

If I do something like this `id_err = $results;`  to see what the query result is it gives me an array to string conversion error.

As hardware intensive as it sounds for this kind of operation, if you think should query the rows directly and count them with PHP please show me how.

I have also tried doing some variation on `$results = $rows['count']` with different names such as 'total', and 'result' but they still post. when I try to see what the query result with `id_err = $results;` it flat out ignores it and posts anyways.

to avoid any confusion for on what $id_err is, it stops the script from posting if it ever gets used.

and to clarify this SQL query is within a conditional statement.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` function returns all records as one row with the count.. so remove the `while` and compare the appropriate index.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(email) as the_count FROM subscribers WHERE id= ?";
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt2->execute();
$callbacks = $stmt2->get_result();
$rows = $callbacks->fetch_assoc();
$stmt2->close();
if ($rows['the_count'] < 2001){
     $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
}else{
     $email_err = "This user has reached the limmit to what their plan can allow .";
}
```